# Error al intentar instalar ruby con rbenv install 2.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy intentando instalar ruby on rails en ubuntu 16.10 haciendo uso de la guia de [rails go](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.10) pero al colocar el comando rbenv install 2.3.3 obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Downloading ruby-2.3.3.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.3.tar.bz2
error: failed to download ruby-2.3.3.tar.bz2

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.10 using ruby-build 20170405-4-g365dd1f)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20170513215503.3865
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20170513215503.3865.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/ruby-build.20170513215503.3865 ~
curl: (18) transfer closed with 11311517 bytes remaining to read
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el log `/tmp/ruby-build.20170513215503.3865.log`?

Comment: @Gerry gracias por responder, en esa carpeta esta es el archivo que descarga el comando rbenv install 2.3.3

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido de ese archivo? Ahí viene mayor detalle del error. Puedes utilizar el comando `tail` para obetenerlo: `tail /tmp/ruby-build.20170513215503.3865.log`. Agrega el resultado de ese comando en tu pregunta.

Comment: También puedes intentar la instalacion con `rbenv install 2.3.3 -v` para ver el error que provocó que no completara la descarga (por la guía a la que haces referencia asumo que usas Rbenv).

Comment: @Gerry este es el resultado de el comando  "tail /tmp/ruby-build.20170514192002.2686.log" /tmp/ruby-build.20170514192002.2686 ~
curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.

Comment: No he tratado con ese error antes, ¿podrías ejecutar `rbenv install 2.3.3 -v `? De esta forma te mostrará con mayor detalle la ejecución y posiblemente podamos ver un error más específico.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que señalas, el problema es que no pudo descargar el archivo. Podría ser útil actualizar ruby-build:

```
cd ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
git pull origin master
cd -
rbenv install 2.3.3
```